# Build System and portability

Tags: cmake, build-system

I'm wondering how i can make a portable build system (step-by-step), i currently use cmake because it was easy to set up in the first place, with only one arch target, but now that i have to package the library I'm developing I'm wondering how is the best way to make it portable for arch I'm testing.

I know I need a config.h to define things depending on the arch but I don't know how automatic this can be.

Any other way to have a build system are warmly welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use CMake, it's pretty straightforward.

You need these things:

First, means to find out the configuration specifics. For example, if you know that some function is named differently on some platform, you can use [`TRY_COMPILE`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:try_compile) to discover that:

```
TRY_COMPILE(HAVE_ALTERNATIVE_FUNC 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/alternative_function_test.cpp
    CMAKE_FLAGS -DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=xxx
)
```

where `alternative_function_test.cpp` is a file in your source directory that compiles only with the alternative definition.

This will define variable `HAVE_ALTERNATIVE_FUNC` if the compile succeeds.

Second, you need to make this definition affect your sources. Either you can add it to compile flags

```
IF(HAVE_TR1_RANDOM)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHAVE_TR1_RANDOM)
ENDIF(HAVE_TR1_RANDOM)
```

or you can make a `config.h` file. Create `config.h.in` with the following line

```
#cmakedefine HAVE_ALTERNATIVE_FUNCS
```

and create a `config.h` file by this line in `CMakeLists.txt` (see [`CONFIGURE_FILE`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:configure_file))

```
CONFIGURE_FILE(config.h.in config.h @ONLY)
```

the `#cmakedefine` will be translated to `#define` or `#undef` depending on the CMake variable.

BTW, for testing edianness, see [this mail](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2005-March/006276.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the GNU autoconf/automake toolchain which has worked well for me so far. I am only really focussed on Linux/x86 (and 64bit) and the Mac, which is important if you are building on a PowerPC, due to endian issues.

With autoconf you can check the host platform with the macro:

```
AC_CANONICAL_HOST
```

And check the endianness using:

```
AC_C_BIGENDIAN
```

Autoconf will then add definitions to config.h which you can use in your code.

I am not certain (have never tried) how well the GNU autotools work on Windows, so if Windows is one of your targets then you may be better off finding similar functionality with your existing cmake build system.

For a good primer on the autotools, have a look here:

http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool

Comment: windows will never be a target for me i hope ;)